# Open Exchange Rates issue to define currency from variable

Tags: javascript

I am fetching a specific currency exchange rate on a specific date through the API in javascript. My code goes like:

```
 var currency = 'KWD';
 var date = '2022-01-01';
 $.get('https://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/' + date + '.json', {app_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX'}, function(data) {
alert("On " + date + ", 1 US Dollar was worth " + data.rates.currency + " "+currency);
           });
```

all works well if I specify the final currency in my code:

```
 $.get('https://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/' + date + '.json', {app_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX'}, function(data) {
alert("On " + date + ", 1 US Dollar was worth " + data.rates.KWD + " "+currency);
           });
```

but i need to fetch the currency from variable currency.
any help on this?

Comment: `data.rates[currency]` https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/#2-square-brackets-property-accessor

Answer (score 1):

As Shreshth stated in a comment above, [you can use square brackets to access object properties from a variable's content](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/#2-square-brackets-property-accessor).

For example...

```js
$.get('https://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/' + date + '.json', {app_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX'}, function(data) {
    alert("On " + date + ", 1 US Dollar was worth " + data.rates[currency] + " "+currency);
});
```